# What is the difference between mechanism and materialism?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, terminology, materialism

Are these two philosophies currently considered synonyms?

Comment: See [Physicalism](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/physicalism/) : today's name for *Materialism*, and [Mechanisms in Science](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/science-mechanisms/).

Comment: What have you tried yourself to find the answer and where did you get stuck? Presuming you have working definitions and/or key figures of both streams, you can compare the two and see where they differ, right?

Comment: @Keelan It seems to me they can't exist independently, so they're at least part of the same philosophy.

Comment: I have a question- have we found every single way of studying a particular thing?
Like biology is a subject which deals with living organisms. Is there a possibility that there are some subjects that humanity has not found yet? I mean a new way of research, study and looking at things? Like nuclear energy was not a subject until it started in 1895 according to wiki. Are there more subjects to be found that deal with other hidden aspects of this world?
Or all ways have been found?

Comment: Maybe something you could pose as a question to the entire forum?

Comment: I tried but don't know how? Can you tell me ?

Comment: If you have a desktop view of http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/ there should be an "[Ask Question](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)" link on the top right. On a mobile device view I think it just reads "Ask"

Comment: If you haven't already, take the tour: http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour and check out the question guidelines here: http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short:

**mechanism**
a belief that the world is causal and explanations
of the world are reducible to physics, chemistry
biochemistry & biology.

**materialism**
a belief that material substance being all there is
implies that [volition](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/action/) and consciousness are the
result of material agency

Note: I'd change your question to "are these two *perspectives* synonymous?" It is a grammatical error and misnomer to consider either "a philosophy" as these are both [world-views](https://www.marxists.org/reference/archive/spirkin/works/dialectical-materialism/ch01-s02.html), not respect for obtaining wisdom (read: [philosophy](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=philosophy)). It is etymological fact that philosophy translates from the Greek and through the Latin to "love of wisdom". This is distinct from "love of perspective upon the world". Wisdom obtains - in fact, requires - knowledge. If perspective could obtain knowledge then the poet's claims regarding a rainbow would have epistemic and ontological equivalence to Newton's [prism](http://micro.magnet.fsu.edu/primer/java/scienceopticsu/newton/). The former is an example of *weltanschauung* (an understanding of what is to you), the latter of *verstehen* (an understanding of what is)

A mechanistic perspective (emphasis my own):

> "We ought then to regard the present state of the universe as the
>   effect of its anterior state and as the cause of the one which is to
>   follow. Given for one instant an intelligence which could comprehend
>   all the forces by which nature is animated and the respective
>   situation of the beings who compose it - an intelligence sufficiently
>   vast to submit these data to analysis - **it would embrace in the same
>   formula the movements of the greatest bodies of the universe and those
>   of the lightest atom**; for it, nothing would be uncertain and the
>   future, as the past, would be present to its eyes."
>   "[A Philosophical Essay on Probabilities](https://www.ime.usp.br/~walterfm/cursos/mac5796/Laplace.pdf)"
>   Pierre Simon, Marquis de LaPlace

As for their overlap, it depends on who is using the terms and how they are using them, so, yes, they *can* be synonymous but are not necessarily so. For a demonstration of the ways to use the term "materialism" as it relates to consciousness, watch this brief excerpt from [a discussion between John Rogers Searle and Robert Lawrence Kuhn](https://youtu.be/6oYk7fMmfIw) (transcription and emphasis my own):

> "Well, it depends of course as we like to say, on how you define these
>   terms. And if you define materialism as the view that matter exists in
>   the sense that all of reality - all of material reality - is all the
>   reality there is; and it has only a third person or objective ontology
>   where it's equally accessible to any competent observer;... and the
>   proposition that consciousness exists is the view that consciousness
>   has a first-person ontology (that it's not part of a third person
>   reality), then, of course, the existence of consciousness trivially
>   would refute materialism...  As always in philosophy you want to get
>   behind the surface issues and see what's actually at stake here. The
>   intelligent materialism is driven by the conviction that the account
>   that we're getting of reality in subjects like physics and chemistry
>   and molecular biology and evolutionary biology - that that ultimately
>   gives us an account of how the world works and I think that's right.
>   If that's materialism, then I'm a materialist, but I also think
>   consciousness exists and it has an irreducible subjective ontology. It
>   only exists when it's experienced by a human or an animal subject - by
>   a conscious agent. But now if you put those two together then my task
>   is to make the existence of consciousness in my sense - the real
>   thing, not some ersatz or simulation, the real thing - consistent with
>   what we know about how the world works. I claim that can be done. So
>   consciousness does not refute my version of materialism, but it does
>   refute certain traditional versions. **What does that tell me? Let's get
>   rid of this terminology of materialism and mentalism and so on and
>   just describe the facts.**"
>   J.R.S.

Comment: OK, they still seem to me like two perspectives that can't exist one without the other (In that case - they would share some kind of common world-view). Is that what you're trying to say?

Comment: Please provide references for those definitions, or explain (ideally using references) why you choose them like this.

Comment: @Probably, edited the answer to address your questions more directly

Comment: After fifth reading I have to tell I'm not sure if I understand how irreducable consciousness can be consistet with materialism. Is the JRS's point that even matter doesn't have to be 100% observable? It's crutial because from your description I understand mechanism as a belief that everything can be observable.

Comment: @Probably That's not abnormal. Good question, tho - post it to the forum? Here's a link to the [articles](http://socrates.berkeley.edu/~jsearle/articles.html) on his homepage. "[Why I am not a Property Dualist](http://socrates.berkeley.edu/~jsearle/PropertydualismFNL.doc)" addresses your question. I just used him as an example to show the overlap with mechanism, the different uses of materialism, and, that the terminology is problematic in that it means different things to different people. As for observability... mechanism is more about explaining everything, but again, depends...

Comment: @Probably such are world-views: they mean different things to different people. One can be a materialist at breakfast, a mechanist at lunch and a dualist for dinner with equal epistemic merit: none. ;)

Comment: @Mr.Kennedy Oh, that makes sense to me, but then mechanism is synonymous with reductionalism :)

Comment: @Probably, I suppose that works in a way that all metaphors are reductions. This is getting off topic, but consider that often times the mind believes it is thinking while merely passing from one metaphor to the next... Anywhoo - hope I've answered your question re: [mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_philosophy), [materialism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialism) and [synonymity](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/synonymity) to a degree of virtuously obtaining knowledge.

Comment: "*It is etymological fact that philosophy translates from the Greek and through the Latin to "love of wisdom".*" Words however do not mean what they meant 2,000 years ago, they mean what they mean now.

Comment: @LuísHenrique certainly and the translation from the Greek has stood 2500+ years. In the context of initial utterance "philo-" translates to our virtue, respect, & reverence but to the point of what is "loved": wisdom. Some have said wisdom is the intelligent application of knowledge, but intelligent according to whom? No, wisdom simply obtains knowledge, it in fact *requires* knowledge, not opinion, not sentiment, not a way of looking at things nor *weltanschauung* (understanding what is "to you") but *verstehen* (understanding what is). Philosophy is heuristic, not hermeneutic.

Comment: @Mr.Kennedy - So, according to you, it would be wrong to say, for instance, "modern philosophy", "Aristotelic philosophy", or "non-sensical philosophy"?

Comment: @LuísHenrique to say those are "wrong" is to state an opinion, to propose a way of looking at things, to offer sentiment where knowledge may be obtained. Often "ethics" are described as a "moral philosophy" but it is self-evident that "moral philosophy" is oxymoron - just as stating "according to my philosophy..." for "according to my perspective upon events..." is merely to wear one's ignorance as if it were a badge of honor.

Comment: @Mr.Kennedy - Sorry, I see no oxymoron in "moral philosophy" or ignorance in "my philosophy". The word is often (perhaps more often than not) used exactly as a shorthand for "perspective of things", "world view", etc. And evidently, things like "Philosophy of Religion" or "Philosophy of Language" have made their way up to well-recognised academic disciplines.

Comment: @LuísHenrique and such is your perogative, however, what knowledge is obtained by perspective? Morals change with time and place; they are perspectival -  i.e. "what is true to [you;me;us;them]" and not "what is". If knowledge were obtained by perspective, then the poet's description of a rainbow as "a bridge made from angels' tears" and Newton's demonstration of prismatic range would have epistemic equivalence. They do not. If knowledge were obtained by perspective, then a mirage and an oasis would have epistemic and ontological equivalence. They do not.

Comment: @LuísHenrique note as well the grammatical difference between "my philosophy" and "philosophy of language" - i.e. "my respect for obtaining knowledge" is "my perspective upon obtaining knowledge" and "philosophy of language" is "respect for obtaining knowledge of [or, from] language". Big difference.